# NullReferenceException when using converter in ItemSource of HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, sorting, treeview

I got a tree view containg TreeViewItems. These TreeViewItems might contain children which are als TreeViewItems in their Items. I want all items to be sorted alphabetically on the root level, as well as all sub-levels (there is 0 or 1 in my implementation).

The tree view is configured like this:

```
<controls:TreeViewEx Name="m_tvLeft" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding LeftColumnItems, Converter={x:Static cv:AlphabeticListSortConverter.Instance}, ConverterParameter=Header}"
                     SelectionChanged="OnTvLeftSelectionChanged"
                     MouseDoubleClick="OnTvLeftItemMouseDoubleClick">
   <controls:TreeViewEx.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="controls:TreeViewExItem">
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
      </Style>
   </controls:TreeViewEx.Resources>
   <controls:TreeViewEx.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="controls:TreeViewExItem">
         <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
      </Style>
   </controls:TreeViewEx.ItemContainerStyle>
   <controls:TreeViewEx.ItemTemplate>
      <!-- Template for root fields -->
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Converter={x:Static cv:AlphabeticListSortConverter.Instance}, ConverterParameter=Header}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"  Tag="{Binding}" />
         <!-- Template for child fields -->
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Tag="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </controls:TreeViewEx.ItemTemplate>
</controls:TreeViewEx>
```

The binding is done onto this property:

```
public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> LeftColumnItems { get; private set; }
```

which is being filled like this for a leaf item:

```
TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem {
                            Header = newColInfo.Name,
                            Tag = newColInfo
                        };
```

and like this for a grouping item having children:

```
TreeViewItem newGroupItem = new TreeViewItem {
                    Header = columnGroup.GroupName,
                    IsExpanded = columnGroup.IsExpanded
                };
```

The converter implementation:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
   IList collection = value as IList;
   if (collection == null) {
      throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The value must be of type IList. Type was {0}", value == null ? "NULL" : value.GetType().ToString()));
   }
   if (parameter == null) {
      throw new NotSupportedException("The parameter must be not NULL.");
   }

   ListCollectionView view = new ListCollectionView(collection);
   SortDescription sort = new SortDescription(parameter.ToString(), ListSortDirection.Ascending);
   view.SortDescriptions.Add(sort);

   return view;
}
```

**Problem:** A NullReferenceException is being thrown here `view.SortDescriptions.Add(sort);` even though none of the objects on my side are null. This does not happen if I add the converter only to the ItemSource of the tree view, but then, the child nodes are not sorted.

I don't understand where this NullReferenceException is coming from, as I'm only operating on TreeViewItems having a value set for the Header property.

Do you understand what's going on?

Comment: Try adding some watch, even hovering mouse on the variable can show you what is actually null, if it happens at `view.SortDescriptions.Add(sort);`, there is a high chance that `view` is null, but looks like it's weird.

Comment: @KingKing view can't be null, it's just been instanciated

Comment: @franssu so I said it's weird, so what could you say what could be null here? or it's just an inner exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All collections have a default `CollectionView`. For all collections implementing `IList`, the `ListCollectionView` object is the default view object. To get the default view, you use the `GetDefaultView` method.

`ListCollectionView` inherits `CollectionView` which implement `ICollectionView`, so it is more safe to retrieve any collection's view as `ICollectionView` and apply sorting, filter etc.

I am not sure about rest of the implementations but using `ICollectionView` you can have more generic sorting

example

```
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection);
        SortDescription sort = new SortDescription(parameter.ToString(), ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(sort);
```

if after this you receive `view` as null then do check if the variable collection is actually a Collection.

more info

[ListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview)

[How to: Get the Default View of a Data Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752284)

Comment: This worked, thanks! I still don't understand why though

Comment: `ListCollectionView` is supposed to retrieved by using `GetDefaultView` method. Secondly `ListCollectionView` inherits `CollectionView` which implement `ICollectionView`, so it is more safe to retrieve any collection's view as ICollectionView and apply sorting, filter etc. more info [Get the Default View of a Data Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752284)